# How will i add background service for countdown timer

Tags: java, android

```
long duration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis((long) 6.3);

new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        String sDuration = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d : %02d"
                            ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)
                            ,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)));

        orderCountdown.setText(sDuration);
    }

    @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            orderCountdown.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
            Toast.makeText(context,"asdasd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }.start();
}
```

how can i add a background service for this code to work in background

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) answer your question?

Comment: I already tried that solution but it doesn't work :( anyway thank you for the suggestion Mr Ivan